# 5.1 analog sound card MacPro

Tags: mac, boot-camp, sound-card, 5.1, mac-pro

To avoid the lack of analog ports in the past I bought a USB headset, it broke recently :( I'd really like to use my [uber pair of headphones](http://www.roccat.org/Products/Gaming-Sound/ROCCAT-Kave-5-1/) unfortunately they use analog so I'm having a little trouble with the MacPro's lack of holes :)

I'm on a MacPro (2009) so I would either need a PCI-e card or an external card. I primarily want to use this headset in Windows7 (bootcamp) but it would be nice to be able to use it in OSX (10.6) as well.

OSX compatible PCI-e sound cards are very expensive and aimed at audio professionals. I've seen a few external sound cards that are USB that seem like they would do the trick and work in Windows and OSX. I don't have any experience with sounds cards so I don't know how an external card would perform. I could just use a PCI-e card like a SoundBlaster and just use it in Windows.

If anyone can suggest a solution that will work on both OS that would be great! I've looked around, it seems many have tried, but most discussions I've read end up being a discussion about what true 5.1 is...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of looking around I went for a [Gamesurround Muse XL Pocket LT3](http://www.hercules.com/uk/Sound-Cards/bdd/p/123/gamesurround-muse-xl-pocket-lt3/)